# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'enable_eager_execution'

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

Running the below from https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker#gpu_support in Ubuntu 18.04/Docker 19.03 and it's failing

docker run --gpus all -it --rm tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu \
   python -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.enable_eager_execution(); print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random_normal([1000, 1000])))"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'enable_eager_execution'

Please help to fix this.

Comment: Could it be that you're using tensorflow 2? Because tensorflow 2 has eager execution by default, and therefore doesn't have the enable_eager_execution function.

Comment: yes i am using tenserflow 2.0.0.

Comment: I am using the code published in the tensorflow site: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker#gpu_support

Comment: just remove the enable_eager_execution() part and it should work. But I think it looks like all of the code between the  citation marks is just meant as an example.

Comment: Removed  and now getting this error:  root@0939-jdeml-w04:/shared_data/isosys/deployment/jmv/gpucputest# docker run --gpus all -it --rm tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu \
>    python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random_normal([1000, 1000])))"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'random_normal'

Comment: The code between citation marks is written for tensorflow 1.x, and tf 2.x is not backwards compatible. If you change random_normal into random.normal this error should go away. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/normal and compare with the 1.x version.

Comment: @simon you should write an answer cause this resolved my issue.